# Foreach with multiple arrays (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I got this code:

```
$result = $phpSigep->calcPrecoPrazo($params);

foreach ($result->getResult() as $key => $shippingCorreios) {
$shipping->service = array(['name' => $shippingCorreios->get('servico')->get('nome')]);
$shipping->amount += $productsToShipping['withRules']['amount'];
dd($shipping);
```

`$result->getResource()` its like this:

```
array:39 [
  0 => CalcPrecoPrazoResposta {#652
    #servico: ServicoDePostagem {#653
      #codigo: "41068"
      #idServico: 109819
      #nome: "Pac 41068"
      #_failIfAtributeNotExiste: true
    }
    #valor: 62.24
    #prazoEntrega: 7
    #valorMaoPropria: 0.0
    #valorAvisoRecebimento: 5.0
    #valorValorDeclarado: 0.57
    #entregaDomiciliar: true
    #entregaSabado: false
    #erroCodigo: 0
    #erroMsg: null
    #_failIfAtributeNotExiste: true
```

I need to run the foreach and return all arrays. Now this code just give me the last array, because foreach cleans its data when it's run again.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

You re-assign `$shipping->service` in each iteration. To add new element to array use `[] =`:

```
foreach () {
    $shipping->service[] = array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to store them in new variable like:

```
$allServices = [];
$result = $phpSigep->calcPrecoPrazo($params);

foreach ($result->getResult() as $key => $shippingCorreios) {
$currentService = array(['name' => $shippingCorreios->get('servico')->get('nome')]);
$allServices[] = $currentService;
$shipping->service = $currentService;
$shipping->amount += $productsToShipping['withRules']['amount'];
dd($shipping);
```

and then simply do whatever you need with the $allServices collection

Comment: i try that way but still returning the last array

Comment: if `$shipping->service` should hold all services, then see what Tom vb posted. definitely a way to go in this case. If not, I'm afraid you have to clarify WHERE you need to use the whole set.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a new array with the following code:

```
$shipping->service = array(['name' => $shippingCorreios->get('servico')->get('nome')]);
```

You should append to your array like this:

```
$shipping->service[] = 'name' => $shippingCorreios->get('servico')->get('nome');
```

For example:

```
$array = ['banana', 'apple'];
$array = array(['coconut']);

var_dump($array);
```

will return this

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "coconut"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found e answer.

```
$array[$key] = [
                                'name' => $shippingCorreios->get('servico')->get('nome'),
                                'value' => $shippingCorreios->get('valor'),
                                'dead line' => $shippingCorreios->get('prazo')
                                ];
```